# Minimize intro part in eclipse application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created my own intro in eclipse application as follows:

```
public class CustomIntro extends IntroPart {
    public void createPartControl(Composite container) {
        //add intro, works perfectly fine
    }

    //override other essential methods
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine, now I want to minimize this intro programatically. Upon a click of button the intro should be minimized. Actually I want to launch a internal browser upon click of button, and the intro should be minimized and launched internal browser should be visible.
As suggested by @greg-449, I extended the IntroPart than implementing IIntropart. Thanks for that, but my issue still remains. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should extend `org.eclipse.ui.part.IntroPart` rather than implementing all the interface methods yourself. `IIntroPart` is marked 'not intended to be implemented by clients'

Comment: oh! i did not know that. Thanks for that. i made the change. But any idea how to achieve this minimize issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) pointed, you should extends `IntroPart` abstract class as is explained in [the documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/IntroPart.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use setPartState().

Use this in your IntroPart:

```
this.getIntroSite().getPage().setPartState(this.getIntroSite().getPage().getActivePartReference(), IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MINIMIZED);
```